# Regular Expression for finding words that are not between "" chars

Tags: c#, json, regex

I'm getting data from a HTTP GET request that is not valid JSON:

```
{       updates : {
                mode_a1 : "Disarm",
                mode_a2 : "Disarm",
                battery : "Normal",
                tamper : "Close",
                interference : "Normal",
                ac_activation : "Normal",
                rssi : "13",
                sig_gsm : "N/A"
        },
        forms : {
                pcondform1 : {
                        mode : "4",
                        f_arm : "0"
                },
                pcondform2 : {
                        mode : "4",
                        f_arm : "0"
                }
        }
}
```

As you can see the properties are not quoted. So I want to get all words, that are not quoted with a regex.
But I don't know how to exclude the words that are already inside the "" chars.

This is what I have so far.
(\w+)

http://regexr.com/4ldtc

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data if you only want to match word characters `\w+` you might use negative lookbehind to check what is on the left is not a non whitespace char and a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is a space `:` space.

```
(?<!\S)\w+(?= : )
```

In the replacement use the full match surrounded by double quotes

```
@"""$0""";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ppmjJg/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/P5sBHu)

Comment: Thank you, 
this one fits my need perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to match only the keys, so you could try to expand your re to match until `:` like this

```
(\w+)(?=\s*:)
```

Comment: This one is perfect.
Thank you